# Problem with filtering Mutablelist of type class

Tags: android, kotlin

So what I'm trying to do is to write search logic. The problem is following filter does not work even tho I do have an element containing following letter. So what my question is why is it not returning the expected value and if I'm doing something wrong what is it.

the filter I'm trying to use:

```
model.data.filter { person -> person.employeeName.toLowerCase().contains("t")}.toMutableList()
```

where model is InfoModel type and InfoModel looks like this:

```
class InfoModel {
    var status = ""
    lateinit var data : MutableList<Data>

    class Data {
        var id = ""
        @SerializedName("employee_name")
        var employeeName = ""
        @SerializedName("employee_salary")
        var employeeSalary = ""
        @SerializedName("employee_age")
        var employeeAge = ""
        @SerializedName("profile_image ")
        var profileImage = "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/146-1468479_my-profile-icon-blank-profile-picture-circle-hd.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing due to lack of context, but maybe you're doing something like this:

```
model.data.filter { person -> person.employeeName.toLowerCase().contains("t")}.toMutableList()
println(model.data) // Still prints original unfiltered list!
```

The first line of code creates a new MutableList and promptly throws it away, because you don't assign it to anything. So the original list pointed at by `model.data` is left unchanged.

Since `data` is a MutableList, you can modify it in place using `retainAll`:

```
model.data.retainAll { person -> person.employeeName.toLowerCase().contains("t") }
```

Alternatively, you could reassign the result of your original code back to `model.data`:

```
model.data = model.data.filter { person -> person.employeeName.toLowerCase().contains("t")}.toMutableList()
```

To me it looks like kind of code smell to have a `MutableList` assigned to a read-write `var`, because then it's mutable in two different ways. Why does it even have to be `lateinit` if it's mutable? You could instantiate with an empty list and fill it later.

In general `var data: List` should be preferred to `val data: MutableList` unless you are needing to optimize performance for huge lists. And `var data: MutableList` is just inviting troubles.

Comment: Thanks for help mate. I was in fact modifying current list but for some reason filter just could not give me the desired result  but retainAll did the job.